# Can you help me identify this pear-shaped fruit?

Tags: identification, fruits, vines

I need help identifying a strange fruit I discovered while camping. Its characteristics are:

- Roughly pear-shaped
- Bright green
- Dark green "spikes" on fruit
- Grown on a vine
- Large seeds (≈1 in)
- Fruit is ≈4 in
- found on cliff face in the San Juans in Washington in the United States

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. Photos are always advised for *identification* questions. You'll get better answers, too, with photos. Can you add one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like something in the cucumber family. There are only two species in Washington State in that family that have green, spiny fruit: wild cucumber (*Echinocystis lobata*) and coastal manroot (*Marah oreganus*). The *Marah* has larger fruit, so I reckon it is probably that, but that species is extremely rare in British Columbia, so I wonder if it is also rare in adjacent coastal areas of Washington. If you have pictures of the fruit, leaves, or flowers, that would help.

---

## COASTAL MANROOT

[image]
[source: [oregonflora.org](http://www.oregonflora.org/imgFull.php?CD=1167&file=MAR_ORE_4714B&taxon=Marah%20oregana&fieldphotonum=dig9746)]

[image]
[source: [oregonflora.org](http://www.oregonflora.org/imgFull.php?CD=1167&file=MAR_ORE_2125B&taxon=Marah%20oregana&fieldphotonum=dig9741)]

[image]
[source: [science.halleyhosting.com](http://science.halleyhosting.com/nature/plants/5petal/cuke/marah/marah.htm)]

## WILD CUCUMBER

[image]
[source: [biolib.cz](http://www.biolib.cz/IMG/GAL/69064.jpg)]

[image]
[source: [flora.nhm-wien.ac.at](http://flora.nhm-wien.ac.at/Seiten-Arten/Echinocystis-lobata.htm)

Comment: From whence comes the name "manroot", btw. Craycray.  http://www.oregonflora.org/showimage.jpg?fieldphotonum=502-20

Comment: Thank you! It was a coastal manroot. Sorry I couldn't get a picture.